# How to center a superfish menu in wordpress (in IE7)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, superfish

I have a wordpress blog with a menu I wanted to style as a superfish dropdown menu and I followed this tutorial: http://kav.in/wordpress-superfish-dropdown-menu

So far the menu looks great but I need it to be centered instead of aligned left. Here is my code:

```
#navwrap {
    float:              left;
    width:              100%;
    background:         url(images/bg.png) repeat transparent;
    text-transform:     uppercase;   
    font-size:          12px;
    height:             40px;
}
.sf-menu {
    float:              left;
    width:              100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.sf-menu li {
    background:         transparent;
}
.sf-menu a {
    padding:            0px 15px;
    text-decoration:    none;
    line-height:        40px;
}
.sf-menu ul li a {
    padding:            0px 15px;
    text-decoration:    none;
}
.sf-menu li li {
    background:         #611718;
    text-align: left;
}
```

The items in my menu have of course variable width.

I don't have the html without all the sf classes but it's a simple list more or less like this:

```
 <div id="navwrap">

    <ul class="sf-menu">

    <li><a href="#">List item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List item</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">List item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Edit: I found a way to center it but it doesn't work in IE7.

Ok, I tried an approach I found searching on google and it seemed to work until I checked IE7, looks like inline-block is making the menu break completely:

```
#navwrap .sf-menu {
   text-align: center;
}
#navwrap .sf-menu li {
   display: inline-block; 
   float: none;
}
#navwrap .sf-menu li a {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

This is the page I'm working on: http://hermandaddelcalvario.org/wordpress/ You can check the top menu in IE7 as it breaks.

Comment: So you **do** have it working, just not on IE7. You are asking the wrong question then. ;)

Comment: That was an edit of what I found after researching for this. I should have stated so, will edit the question again

Comment: So work on fixing it on IE now. Add a CSS that only affects `IE<=7`. Also, the problem is that IE7- refuses to display as `inline-block` elements that are originally `block` elements. Sorry that I don't have the time to look into this.

Comment: Well I'm in no hurry, I will play with IE7 only statements to see what I can do, if you can look at it later or any other day please do. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Ye, if I had a working example of your problem it would be easier. How to add a IE7- only CSS: `<!--[if lt IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->`

Comment: You can check it here: http://hermandaddelcalvario.org/wordpress/ tho I'm playing with the ie7 thing atm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE7 does not like inline-block for elements that are originally block-level elements.
But you are not using any margin on the `li`s, so why not use `display: inline;` instead? I think it would not make any difference whatsoever.

It seems that using inline makes the menu disappear.
Removing the `float: left;` seems to fix that.

(Why is the menu floated, anyway? It does not seem to make any difference.)

Comment: the menu is floated because that's the css of superfish (I supposed it was doing something). If I change the inline-block to inline then the drop down menu breaks, the items will act as inline elements and go one after the other. I guess I'd have to hack that or something.

Comment: Nvm that last comment, it's working now, thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    left:     50%;
    width:    100%;

}

#navwrap {
    float:              left;
    width:              100%;
    background:         url(images/bg.png) repeat transparent;
    text-transform:     uppercase;   
    font-size:          12px;
    height:             40px;
    position:           relative;
        left:           -25%;
}
```

And have #navwrap inside .wrapper.
The list won't be truly centred, but it's as close as you'll get, really.

Comment: it didn't center it for me :S

Comment: My mistake, the last value should be -25%. Will that do it?

Comment: That moved the whole div to the right and the rest of the content to the left :S

Comment: Try tweaking the left values until it looks centred.